# Unable to remotely access Backpack CRUD Panel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-backpack

I am currently working on a CRUD panel for a database using Backpack for Laravel. This database is stored on a server run off of an Amazon EC2 instance. While connected to the instance, I am able to access the CRUD Panel using the localhost address after using `php artisan serve`.

I am not able to access the CRUD panel remotely; when I attempt to use the instance's public IP address with the appropriate port to access the panel (i.e., `xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000/admin`), the site can't be reached.

Port 8000 is open for inbound and outbound in the security group for the instance. The server is configured using a WIMP stack; I am unsure if switching to a WAMP stack would be an effective solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll preface my answer with I wouldn't condone doing this unless you are testing the application and are only opening traffic to your ip. **php artisan serve** is an extension of the php build in server.  It's meant to be a tool to run your code during application development on your localhost.  Here is some [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) of the function on php.net with a warning included on using this in production.  You should use a proper service to serve calls to your web application like nginx or apache.

This is how you would serve your page using php artisan serve from your ec2 instance:

1. modify your php artisan serve command to include 0.0.0.0 as the host:

`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

2. In the AWS console, go to your ec2 instances Security Group linked to your server and add an inbound rule to allow traffice to route to port 8000

[image]

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: You were right - we simply forgot about firewall issues. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelR  happy to help and welcome to stack overflow!  Please be sure to upvote and flag the answer as the right one if it it was correct 